# Arrow head shape in Python pyvis

Tags: python, directed-graph, pyvis

I am using the Python pyvis library to plot a directed graph. Is there a way to make arrowheads behave properly when we increase the size of the edges?

Currently, they look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7mgb.png

And I would like the point of the arrowhead to match the end of the edge, instead of the edge continuing after the end of the arrow.

Reproducible code:

````
from pyvis.network import Network

nt = Network(directed=True)
nt.add_node('A',
           size=20,
           color='#ACDBC9',
           borderWidth=0,
           font='30px arial black')
nt.add_node('B',
           size=20,
           color='#ACDBC9',
           borderWidth=0,
           font='30px arial black')
nt.add_edge("A", to="B",
            value=20, color='rgb(247, 167, 166)',
            arrowStrikethrough=True)
nt.set_edge_smooth('curvedCW')
nt.toggle_physics(False)
nt.show('img.html')```
````

Comment: Just use `arrowStrikethrough=False` , when adding edge.